# Using not(:last-child) correctly inside a list

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am trying to reach all but the last element inside an ul/li list but can't get it to work... any help would be much appreciated. The structure is something like this:

```
<ul class="xxx">
 <li>
  <figure>
   [different divs / content]
  </figure>
 </li>
 <li>
  <figure>
   [different divs / content]
  </figure>
 </li>
<ul>
```

What I am trying to do is add some CSS (border-bottom) to all but the last  element...

```
.xxx{
 figure:not(:last-child) {
  /* attributes */
 }
}
```

... what do I do wrong here...? :-) Thanks a million in advance.

Comment: All the `<figure>` elements are the
[`:last-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child), 
[`:first-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child) and [`:only-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:only-child) of their respective parent-elements; so target the `<li>`: `li:not(:last-child) figure {/* css */}`

Comment: @DavidThomas, that was sooo fast and perfect answer, thanks a lot. Please drop an answer that I can approve... :-)

Comment: Thank you so much! But there's no real point, Quentin gave the correct answer already :)

Comment: Quentins answer is almost same as yours with the only difference that it has the > before figure ... and that doesn't work (in my case, im not sure why...) - and as I can't comment on his answer, I didn't want to mark it as correct as it didn't work 100% for me... :-)

Answer (score 0):

Every `figure` element you have is the last (and only) element in its container.

If you want to target the `figure` inside every `li` that is not the last element in the `ul` then you need to apply the pseudo-class to the right element (the `li`).

```
li:not(:last-child) > figure
```